# Custom Continuous Colorbar For Gridded Data

Tags: matplotlib, colormap, cartopy

I am displaying gridded data using matplotlib and Cartopy, and would like to utilize a custom continuous color table that does not currently exist in the default tables. The table looks as follows:

[image: Custom Colorbar]

I have taken the hex codes from this table at every 5 steps, and have written the following code:

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#a700a5','#f200c1','#c80370','#9d121a','#c87e7c','#faf8f8','#98c2fe','#0771ff','#00a0fe','#00f2fc','#02ecbd','#08bd27','#5bcb01','#d4f200','#ffce00','#ff8100','#ff3200','#c10700','#bb5c5b','#e9bfbc','#9f7e74','#7a4d48','#823f4c','#57037b'])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-30, vmax=120)
im = plt.contourf(lons, lats, temp, levels=vals, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, transform=crs.LambertConformal())
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

The plot successfully generates, however, appears as a discrete colorbar as opposed to a continuous ramp between the colors defined in [`mpl.colors.ListedColormap()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html). Is there a way to define a continuous ramp based off of the provided colors?

Comment: Can you provide a complete working example, e.g. defining lons, lats etc...
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that will help with answering

Comment: @Ianhi I've posted this in image form to better show everything at once in the script, it is found here on Imgur: https://imgur.com/HUxqDIw. Thank you for looking it over

Comment: @Ianhi The resultant image of the script can be found here too: https://imgur.com/IKincSY

Comment: It'd be better still if you could edit your question with a snippet of code that will run (maybe generate fake data instead of loading it from your computer) and that demonstrates the issue.  The goal being to let people take the code and run it and then play with it in order to be understand.